# A problem with the output of a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

i'm a beginner in JavaScript and I've just learned about functions and arrays and I've a problem with the code below :
First i had defined the next array:

```
let WorkerS = {
    Php : "Alexander",
    Python : "Vadim",
    Html : "Vladimir",
    JS : "Fyodor",
};
```

Then i defined this simple function:

```
    const Element = (Language) => {
    return WorkerS.Language
};
```

And when i call:

```
console.log(Element(Php));
```

it gives me an error:

```
ReferenceError: Php is not defined
```

, please help me to know where the error is:

Comment: You want `return WorkerS[Language];`

Comment: You also want to provide a string to your function, like `Element('Php')`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
const Element = (Language) => {
  return WorkerS[Language];
};
```

and then change your call to

```
console.log(Element('Php')); //as you can see Php is a string
```

Comment: is there a way to input directly : console.log(Element(Php)) and turn "Php" into a string from the inside of the function ?

Comment: no, if you'll use only  Php then it has to be a declared variable before the Element(Php) call